# How can I remove the grid lines

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I am a learning `Drupal`. I have created an `image gallery` using the `grid` as `style` using `Views`. My question is how can I remove the `grid` on my image gallery? I tried but I could not found any solution.

So can you help me for that?

Comment: show the codes of image gallery...

Comment: Need more clarification - 1. Are you looking at removing `Grid` styling? 2. Are you looking at removing just `Grid Borders` from the gallery? Try uploading a screenshot of the views screen.

Comment: I don't have reputation more then 9. I created a  view for image gallery. I used for that grid. I won't to remove the grid border from grid. I used display none but its not working. when I add another row then border will generated.I wont to remove border from <tbody>, <tr> , <td> so how can i remove from them ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for my problem.I have just give the class for `<tr><td>`**diplay:none** in view. After that I create a another css class in style.css file for `<table class='abc'>`**diplay:none**. That's it

Answer (score -2):

It can be achieved using CSS
Just use firebug or chrome to inspect the element (image container)
And use

.YOURGRIDELEMENT { border: none;}

In your theme CSS file